# Revert JSON on php script

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have JSON -

```
{"First name": "John", "Contact": "2323",...}
```

with arbitrary number of key/value pairs. My `$.ajax`-function sends JSON to a php script. The PHP script must revert JSON and back to jQuery.

```
{"John": "First name", "2323": "Contact",...}
```

PHP code for this iteration and jQuery handling code for response?

Comment: Show some code or be more specific on your madder.

Comment: Is the PHP script doing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

PHP [json_decode()](http://pl2.php.net/manual/pl/function.json-decode.php) then [array_reverse](http://pl2.php.net/manual/pl/function.array-reverse.php) and [json_encode()](http://pl2.php.net/manual/pl/function.json-encode.php)

In jQuery get data by .ajax with dataType: 'json' and array will be ready to use.

I think that application logic shouldn't rely on array elements order

Comment: Not `array_reverse`, but `array_flip`. Not the order of the elements is changed, but the value becomes the key and the key the value.

Comment: yes, you're right, didn't pay enough attention when reading question